# Define click event for UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uisegmentedcontrol

I have added a `UISegmentedControl` in my application.  None of the buttons are selected in normal state.  I want to implement a button click event when the first segment is selected, and another event when another button is clicked.

Comment: How do i set plain segment in UISegmented Control. Thanks.

Comment: @Pugal devan 
set the segment control style property segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBordered;

Answer (score 132, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you simply have to implement a target-action method (supported by [`UIControl`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618259-addtarget) which is `UISegmentedControl`'s parent class) for the constant `UIControlEventValueChanged`, exactly like in the example given in UISegmentControl's [reference documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol).

i.e.

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(action:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

used for a message with the following signature:

```
- (void)action:(id)sender
```

or

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(action:forEvent:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

for

```
- (void)action:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

or

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(action)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

for the simplest method:

```
- (void)action
```

which are standard types of target-action selectors used in UIKit.

Comment: Just a quick heads up: I believe if you define the method as -(void)action then you'll want the selector to be @selector(action) or else it will crash.

Comment: The selector must match the message exactly, but without parameters, so @selector(action:forEvent:) is the selector for "- (void)action:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event"

Comment: I have a question, will this action be called even if I change the selected index manually? If I don't want that to happen can I listen to some other control event?

Comment: Surely you've figured it out by now, but no, the target is not notified on changes applied using code. Only through user's action.

Answer (score 69):

try this:

```
- (IBAction)segmentSwitch:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
      NSInteger selectedSegment = sender.selectedSegmentIndex;

      if (selectedSegment == 0) {

      }
      else{

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

Simple version in swift updated

```
func loadControl(){
     self.yourSegmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentSelected(sender:)), forControlEvents: .valueChanged)
}

func segmentSelected(sender: UISegmentedControl)
{
    let index = sender.selectedSegmentIndex

    // Do what you want
}
```

Comment: latest swift syntax: self.segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentSelected(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)

Answer (score 9):

Try this one,

```
    UISegmentedControl  * travelModeSegment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSLocalizedString(@"Driving", nil),                 NSLocalizedString(@"Walking", nil), nil]];
    [travelModeSegment setFrame:CGRectMake(9.0f, 0.0f, 302.0f, 45.0f)];
    [cell addSubview:travelModeSegment];
    [travelModeSegment release];
```

then write an action,

```
     if (travelModeSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        //write here your action when first item selected
    } else {
        //write here your action when second item selected
    }
```

I hope it will help you

Answer (score 7):

It's worth noting that the selector has to match a method exactly, but without the actual parameters.

```
@selector(action)
    => -(void) action { ..code.. }

@selector(action:) 
    => -(void) action:(id)sender { ..code.. }

@selector(action:forEvent:) 
    => -(void) action:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event { ..code.. }
```

This confused me for the longest time, and it's not quite clear from the earlier answers.

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort in making your explanation, Jonathan. This has been one of those things I've needed to clarify for myself for ... <wonders what sounds like a reasonable admission to my peers> erm ... 'quite sometime now' ;-) 'Nicely presented, too; it's gone straight in my code library! :-)

Answer (score 6):

for SWIFT use this:

```
segmentedControl.addTarget( self, action: "segmentSelected:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged )
```

and implement a method like this:

```
func segmentSelected(sender: UISegmentedControl)
{
    println("selected index: \(sender.selectedSegmentIndex)")
}
```

Extend UISegmentedControl if you want to call a specific action when the selected segment is selected:

```
class CustomSegmentedControl : UISegmentedControl
{        
    override init()
    {
        super.init()
    }

    override init(frame:CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame:frame)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func valueChanged(index:Int)
    {
         // ACTION GOES HERE
    }      
}
```

and call your "valueChanged" in "segmentSelected" like this:

```
func segmentSelected(sender: CustomSegmentedControl)
{
    println("selected index: \(sender.selectedSegmentIndex)")
    sender.valueChanged(sender.selectedSegmentIndex)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple like that, you need to make the action using the storyboard to the view controller in order to make this action to work.

```
- (IBAction)searchSegmentedControl:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
    switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"First was selected");
            break;
        case 1:
            NSLog(@"Second was selected");
            break;
        case 2:
            NSLog(@"Third was selected");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can attach a handler in IB to the value changed event: UIControlEventValueChanged

or you can do it in code:

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(action:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```