# Segmented Controls are not changing my variable's value

Tags: iphone, variables, if-statement, uisegmentedcontrol, xcode4.6

I have a segmented control that should change the value of my variable when each segmented control button is selected. For example, if button 0 is selected the variable should be assigned "1000" or if button 1 is selected then the variable should be assigned the value "2000".

```
-(IBAction)segmentbutton1:(id)sender {

    if (segmentController1.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        settingVar1 = 1000;
    }
    if (segmentController1.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        settingVar1 = 2000;
    }
    if (segmentController1.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
        settingVar1 = 3000;
    }
}
```

I synthesized the variable "settingVar1" in my .m file

```
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@synthesize settingVar1;
```

and I declared it in my .h file.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    int settingVar1;
```

and I also made the variable property in the .h file also.

```
@property (nonatomic)int settingVar1;
```

Is there something that I need to change? If you need to see any other code please let me know. Thanks in advance for any advice that is given.

Comment: put some log in your code, how do you know it's not changed ? is the function really called?

Comment: I did add a NSLog and the value returns "0" every time. 
**bold** 'NSLog(@"settingVar1 equals %i", settingVar1);'

Comment: Put some log to see if `segmentbutton1:` was called or not, and what's the value of `segmentController1.selectedSegmentIndex`

Answer (score 0):

Check please you should do it like this:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [segmentController1 addTarget: self
                           action: @selector(segmentbutton1:)
                 forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

- (IBAction) segmentbutton1: (id)sender 
{
    if (segmentController1.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        settingVar1 = 1000;
    }
    if (segmentController1.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        settingVar1 = 2000;
    }
    if (segmentController1.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
        settingVar1 = 3000;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get help from this link: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049169/how-to-define-click-event-for-uisegmentedcontrol-in-iphone)

Please check that your action method is connected in `xib` file with the `UISegmentedControl` or not.
The better way to change the value. you should use this

```
-(IBAction) segmentbutton1: (id)sender 
{
        settingVar1 = (segmentController1.selectedSegmentIndex + 1) * 1000;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In my .xib file (attributes selector tab)I had the first button in my segment controller "selected" by default, so when I tested the app I did not click on any of the segment control buttons because I assumed that the impressed button would have a value. I removed the "selected" option from the segment controls which forced me to have to click a button and the formula worked. Thanks to all who offered me help.