# How to get value from segmented control to know which one was picked

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to be able to use a segmented control, but I don't know how to get the value for which one was picked. I want to know so I can use a boolean value to determine between the two that were picked

Comment: Use the `selectedSegmentIndex` property. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define click event for UISegmentedControl in iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049169/how-to-define-click-event-for-uisegmentedcontrol-in-iphone)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add method for segment using

```
[YourSegment addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (IBAction)segmentAction:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{    
    NSString * theTitle = [sender titleForSegmentAtIndex:sender.selectedSegmentIndex]
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Look at this:

```
- (IBAction)onSegmentValueChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
        switch ([sender selectedSegmentIndex]) {
            case 0:

                break;
            case 1:

                break;
            case 2:

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```